# Intersecting multiple feature classes with just one feature class?

Tags: arcgis-pro, feature-class, intersect

I have multiple feature classes (fc) and would like to intersect them with one other fc, is this possible without merging/joining the multiple fc's?

Using ArcGIS Pro I've attempted to intersect numerous point layers and a line layer but I actually want to intersect the numerous points to just the line. I've just joined the points to do this but I wanted to avoid this, if there is a way around this?

Comment: Software? Type of data? Your attempts/efforts? Desired Output?

Comment: Sorry! Using ArcGIS Pro. I've attempted to intersect numerous point layers and a line layer but I actually want to intersect the numerous points to just the line. I've just joined the points to do this but I wanted to avoid this, if there is a way around this? *Thank you*

Comment: Please edit your Question with those vital Details. Thank you

Comment: Merge the Points then intersect. Why do you want to avoid merging them?

Comment: I've done this, thank you, I realise this works much better. I wanted to avoid merging because it felt easier to work with the data but I realise this is not the case. THANKS (:

Comment: Have you tried to intersect in batch?

Comment: If you mean listing multiple feature classes in brackets, yes I have. If that's not what you're referring to then no...?